# ¿Cómo traducir la expresión idiomática inglesa "as is"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Me gusta mucho la frase idiomática inglesa "as is":

> [**as is**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-is)
>
> in the state that something is in at the present time:
>
> *Will you wait till it's finished or take it home as is?*

Aparece con frecuencia en sitios como mensajes de los programas informáticos con frases del tipo:

> Disclaimer. THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED **"AS IS"** AND ANY EXPRESSED OR
>   IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED ...

Así que me estaba preguntando: ¿cuál sería la mejor manera de decirlo en castellano?

Se me ocurren opciones como:

- tal y como es/viene
- tal cual

Pero no sé si estoy perdiendo algo en la traducción. ¿Hay algún nativo inglés que pueda dar su opinión?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para tu primer ejemplo, yo usualmente uso:

> tal y como está

que es básicamente lo que tienes en tu primera opción. Para tu segundo ejemplo, yo usaría:

> sin garantía

o

> sin garantía alguna

ya que ese es el contexto en el que se usa "as is".

Answer (score 6):

En general, «*tal cual*» lo traduce perfectamente. Pero para el contexto específico de licencias de software, puede que tenga alguna connotación técnica que sólo conocen los abogados californianos.

Answer (score 1):

En Latinoamerica se dice:

1. A como está. (se refiere a las condiciones o características actuales)
2. A como está y sin futuros reclamos.
3. Según condiciones actuales. (igual que el primero)
4. A como se encuentra.

**NOTA:** Todas las anteriores se entiende que no hay garantía o reclamos para el futuro.