# Traducción de 'Disclaimer'

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, lenguaje-jurídico

Revisando la pregunta [¿"Feedback" en castellano?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13606/feedback-en-castellano) por la cual fedorqui obtuvo su *"Notable question badge"* (felicitaciones) encontré una respuesta que me gustó pero empieza con un **Disclaimer**. Esta respuesta está así desde 2015 y nadie se ha atrevido a editar el anglicismo y corregirlo al español.

Una búsqueda en este sitio muestra que la palabreja en inglés es muy usada incluso en preguntas en español.

Esta otra [pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13567/c%C3%B3mo-traducir-la-expresi%C3%B3n-idiom%C3%A1tica-inglesa-as-is) sobre **AS IS** cita el texto "Disclaimer. THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND..." pero no se discute sobre "Disclaimer".

Muchas veces le damos el significado de "Aclaración" o "Anotación" el cual no es exactamente su real significado de "renuncia de responsabilidad" o "descargo de responsabilidad", pero aunque este último es claro para la mayoría, ¿existe una manera más simple y clara en español?

Comment: Disclaimer: cuando has formulado [unas cuantas preguntas](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui?tab=questions&sort=views), conseguir medallas por visitas solo es cuestión de tiempo y SEO. ¡Muy agradecido de que mi pregunta te sea de utilidad y análisis! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***DESCARGO DE RESPONSABILIDAD***
>
> *La respuesta que aquí se ofrece está basada en los conocimientos y experiencias personales de su autor. Los puntos de vista en ella declarados son responsabilidad del autor exclusivamente y Spanish.SE no se responsabiliza de los mismos.*

El término que más he visto usar es el de "**descargo de responsabilidad**".
Muchas veces puedes encontrar ["descarga" en vez de "descargo"](https://www.google.es/search?q=descargo%20de%20responsabilidad), pero es un uso incorrecto de "descarga".
Algunas empresas como Google usan también "[renuncia de responsabilidad](https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=es&gl=es#toc-warranties-disclaimers)"; mientras que otras como Mozilla usan "[exclusión de garantías](https://www.mozilla.org/es-ES/about/legal/terms/mozilla/#1046-exclusion-de-garantias-y-limitacion-de-responsabilidad)".

**La RAE utiliza el término ["exención de responsabilidad"](https://enclave.rae.es/condiciones-de-uso)**, que además cuadra bastante bien si miramos la definición:

> [**exención**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HEDFzOj)
>
> 2. f. Franqueza y libertad que alguien goza para eximirse de algún cargo u obligación.

Y que seguramente sería el más correcto, semánticamente hablando.

Answer (score 3):

**Aviso**

Disclaimer: Depende del contexto, por supuesto, pero en casos serios (por ejemplo, licencias...) suele usarse la expresión *Aviso Legal*.

Para un uso más general, diría que la fórmula más sencilla sería dar un *aviso*, simplemente. En alguna ocasión he visto también el uso del verbo exonerar, pero la verdad es que es un uso más extraño.

Answer (score 3):

Mi primer instinto es traducirlo como **'renuncia'** o como **'recusación'**.

Probablemente porque suelo ver la palabra 'disclaimer' en el ámbito web lo asocio a 'renuncia de responsabilidad' (y de hecho, puedes buscar 'renuncia de responsabilidad' en Google y verás que se usa en ese sentido).

Y en la misma dirección, la RAE acepta [recusación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VXq9CuT) como

> 1. tr. No querer admitir o aceptar algo.

aunque en el ámbito estrictamente jurídico tiene una acepción más específica.

Answer (score 2):

Una buena traducción sería:

> deslinde (de responsabilidad[es])

Deslinde, según la RAE es la acción y efecto de deslindar.
Deslindar, según la misma fuente es (segunda acepción):

> Aclarar algo, de modo que no haya confusión en ello.

Eso cuadra muy bien con la definición de Merriam-Webster citada por @Carlos Alejo.

El Diccionario Integral del Español de la Argentina (ed.Voz Activa) dice:

> Deslindar (segunda acep): Separar unas cosas de otras con el fin de distinguirlas y determinarlas

Y da el ejemplo:

> *La comisión debería deslindar las responsabilidades políticas*.

También define deslindarse como:

> 1 *intr*. Mostrar o dejar en claro que no se está vinculado con algo a alguien. *Llamó a conferencia de prensea para deslindarse del atentado*. || 2 *intr* No hacerse cargo de una responsabilidad o de un problema: *Intenta deslindarse de sus obligaciones*.

Y a continuación define deslinde:

> 1 (...) || 2 *m* Separación de cosas que se realiza con el fin de distinguirlas o determinarlas: *el deslinde de responsabilidades*

Parece una familia de palabras más que adecuada para cláusulas legales y avisos que básicamente dicen: "hasta acá nos hacemos cargo, más no", lo cual también remite a la primera acepción que dan ambos diccionarios (y cuya búsqueda dejo como ejercicio para el lector).

Comment: [Deslindar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D8K1LYb) significa "aclarar o señalar". Podrías elaborar un poco más sobre cómo el uso de "deslindar" responde a la pregunta? Gracias.

Comment: @Diego Lo pedís, lo tenés. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

El uso actual de *disclaimer* en inglés asociado a los foros de internet viene reflejado por dictionary.com como:

> [disclaimer in Technology](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disclaimer?s=t)
>   networking
>   Statement ritually appended to many Usenet postings (sometimes automatically, by the posting software) reiterating the fact (which should be obvious, but is easily forgotten) that the article reflects its author's opinions and not necessarily those of the organisation running the computer through which the article entered the network.

Es decir, el legalismo *disclaimer* (*prevención de quejas*, etimológicamente) no sea usa como el *descargo de responsabilidad* que [indica WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=disclaimer) sino como algo más campestre del tipo *aviso*, tal y como [dice carrdelling](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17584/1674).

Teniendo en cuenta que es un texto usado en ámbitos internetísticos foriles (si existe tal palabro), no hace falta tomarla con mucha rimbombancia y poner cosas como *aviso legal*, a menos que uno quiera mantener el tono jocoso con el que entiendo que se usa en inglés.

A mí me convence pues decir:

> **Aviso**: este software...

O incluso más informal:

> **¡Ojo!** este software...

Answer (score 1):

Para este tipo de situaciones yo lo primero que hago es comprobar la definición en inglés de la palabra para asegurarme de qué estamos hablando. En el Merriam-Webster aparecen [dos definiciones](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disclaimer):

> A statement that is meant to prevent an incorrect understanding of something (such as a book, a movie, or an advertisement).

Un ejemplo de este significado sería *the documentary opens with a disclaimer that many of its scenes are “fictional re-creations” of real events*.

> A denial or disavowal of legal claim:  relinquishment of or formal refusal to accept an interest or estate.

Ejemplo de esta sería *one brother filed a disclaimer, allowing all of the estate to go to his poorer siblings*.

En el primer caso se podría traducir por un simple **aviso**. El segundo caso se podría traducir por la opción que propone el traductor de Google: **renuncia**.

Sin embargo, esa renuncia se puede entender en algunas ocasiones, dentro del ámbito jurídico, como una renuncia de la responsabilidad que podría surgir a partir de determinadas situaciones, y en ese caso es cuando se podría traducir por

> **descarga de responsabilidad**

(o como ***aviso legal***, propuesto en otra respuesta con la que estoy de acuerdo). De hecho, la primera acepción comentada podría entenderse por ahí, como una descarga de responsabilidad en caso de que el que vea el documental lo entienda como lo que no es y saque conclusiones erróneas. El que avisa no es traidor.

Así pues, un *disclaimer* en su primera acepción podría ser un aviso que se expone con el propósito específico de evitar malentendidos. Parece que el término exoneración, ya comentado, podría valer, pero lo veo muy forzado. A fin de cuentas, [exonerar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HGptCOJ) significa "descarga de obligación", que no es lo mismo que una descarga de responsabilidad.

Comment: Normalmente el 'aviso' cuando no es de ámbito legal, lo interpreto como una 'aclaratoria'.

Answer (score 0):

> **EXCLUSIÓN DE GARANTÍAS**

(sacado de la respuesta de walen)

Me gusta porque también los estudiantes del español lo entenderían.

También propongo

> **CLÁUSULA DE AUSENCIA DE GARANTÍA Y LIMITACIÓN DE RESPONSABILIDADES**

que saqué de linguee.com como traducción de "DISCLAIMER OF WARRANTIES AND LIMITATION OF LIABILITY".  Esta me gusta porque tiene el tono legalístico exagerado que hace funcionar "DISCLAIMER" como prólogo jocoso en un post de StackExchange.  De hecho se podría usar ya sea la primera mitad o la segunda mitad para dar el efecto deseado, es decir

> **CLÁUSULA DE AUSENCIA DE GARANTÍA**

o sea

> **LIMITACIÓN DE RESPONSABILIDADES**

Si uno quiere dar el mismo efecto pero con un poquito más sutileza, se podrían abandonar las mayúsculas.

*DGaleano, una pregunta: ¿te has animado a editar algunas respuestas para quitar el anglicismo?*