# ¿Por qué "don, doña" para el nombre pero "señor, señora" para el apellido?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, formalidad, diferencias-entre-palabras

El uso actual, al menos en España, dicta que "don, doña" se usa normalmente solo para los nombres; y que para los apellidos se debe usar "señor, señora":

- Don Arturo, pero señor Pérez-Reverte;
- Doña Ángela, pero señora Merkel;
- Don Rodrigo, pero señor Díaz;
- Doña Jessica, pero señora Rabbit.

No estaría bien decir, por ejemplo "Don Céspedes"; aunque sí sería válido "señor Francisco".
<sub>Es cierto que a veces se rompe la regla y se dice, por ejemplo, "Doña Merkel"; pero tengo la sensación de que usarlo así introduce un matiz ligeramente distinto...</sub>

En cualquier caso, ¿por qué es esto así? ¿Por qué no al revés, si "don" viene de *dominus* que significa "señor"? **¿Por qué "don, doña" para los nombres pero "señor, señora" para los apellidos?**

Answer (score 3):

> [Descargo de responsabilidad](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17583/12637): en esta respuesta usaré *señor* para referirme tanto a *señor* como a *señora*. Igualmente, usaré *don* para tanto *don* como *doña*.

---

Históricamente, el tratamiento de *[**señor**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Se%C3%B1or)* presuponía nobleza, potestad o heroicidad, aunque ya en el siglo XVIII aparece recogido en el *Autoridades* con la acepción de que era usado como tratamiento para referirse a otras personas, ya sean iguales o incluso inferiores. En cambio, *[**don**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_(tratamiento))* siempre ha sido usado como expresión de cortesía y respeto, sin que este indique título alguno. Su uso hoy día implica simplemente que la persona ha alcanzado una cierta edad o estudios (aún recuerdo a mi abuelo diciéndome que ya se me podía decir "don Carlos" cuando cumplí los 18).

Pero ¿por qué uno se usa con el nombre y otro con el apellido? La Wikipedia dice:

> En su uso original se anteponía solamente al nombre de pila o al nombre de pila seguido del apellido. Así, al distinguido Juan Esquer se le daba indistintamente el tratamiento de don Juan o don Juan Esquer. En el caso de usar sólo el apellido, el tratamiento correcto era el *señor Esquer*.

Dice también:

> Se usa el título «señor» antepuesto al apellido, generalmente para expresar la condición de casado. Es así en expresiones como: «El señor y señora González».

Esto cuadra con su origen como título, puesto que los títulos se heredaban dentro de una familia, por lo que al final prevalecía el apellido familiar que era lo que se transmitía igualmente. El cambio el tratamiento *don* se usaba con las personas individuales, de las cuales el nombre era lo que realmente las distinguía. Y además no se transmitía, sino que cada individuo se lo tenía que ganar.

Se encuentran usos siguiendo esta misma pauta desde antiguo:

> *[...] e a pedimiento del dicho señor Velez e del dicho concejo e vecinos de Araia, fize escriuir este testimonio [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Sentencia de pleito [Documentación medieval de la cuadrilla de Salvatierra]", 1455 (España).

Y desde más antiguo aún *don* , dado que se encuentran ejemplos ya en el siglo XI, en textos en latín:

> *Facta carta in manu don Lope, prioris Sancta Maria de Neguosa [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Donación de fincas en Tafalla y Nicuesa [Documentos correspondientes al reinado de Sancho Ramírez]", 1094 (España).

Y en *El Cid*, de 1140, recordemos a "don Elvira e doña Sol".

Resumiendo: entiendo que esta diferencia en cuanto al origen de ambas palabras es la que marcó que una se usara con los apellidos (lo que se transmitía junto con el título en el caso de *señor*) o con el nombre (lo que distinguía a cada persona individual en el caso de *don*).

Comment: @walen pues esa es buena. Mientras rebuscaba en el CORDE me di cuenta de que había textos del siglo XII, contemporáneos del _Myo Cid_, que usan _sennor_ junto a nombres, así que entiendo que al principio debió de haber una especie de confusión entre ambas voces, y al final se decantaron por el uso actual, pero no sabría decir más.

Answer (score 1):

En México, "don" y "doña" usualmente denotan tanto deferencia como familiaridad con la persona. Por ejemplo, si conozco personalmente al dueño de la empresa donde trabajo, me sentiría cómodo diciéndole "don Carlos". Nótese que usar el nombre de pila refuerza la idea de que tengo una relación personal con el interlocutor.

En cambio, "señor" y "señora" denotan respeto y distancia. Por ejemplo, el Presidente siempre es presentado como el "señor Presidente de la República". Usar el apellido refuerza esta idea de distancia y respeto.

Como bien indicas, combinar la regla y usar "don Slim" o "el señor López Obrador" denotan familiaridad y distancia el mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Según tengo entendido en respuesta al porque usar el término Don + "el nombre de pila" es por respeto. Pero que ocurre lo contrario al usarlo como Don + "el apellido", ya que al ser el nombre de pila con el cual se es bautizado, usar el término Don con solo el apellido denota desinterés por la persona mencionada ....En resumen por ejemplo, decirle a alguien "Don Pérez" , sería como decirle "Don X, Don cualquiera, un Don Pérez cualquiera que sea". Lo que se entiende como un insulto por estar "ninguneando" o desvalorando a la persona mencionada.

Answer (score 0):

Pues mi mamá siempre nos dijo que era una falta de respeto si se utilizaba el Don o Doña y el apellido era una manera muy grosera de llamarle a la persona en cambio si le decías  Don o Doña y el nombre de pila de la persona era una manera de demostrar respeto a la persona,pero si podíamos utilizar Señor o Señora con el nombre o el apellido de la persona y se oye con respeto